# How can I set the color of a specific note and/or link in a google chart sankey diagram?

Tags: colors, google-visualization, sankey-diagram

**Here is what my data may look like:**

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Customers');
    data.addRows([
      ['BOUGHT FIRST FROM YOU','your customers',29],
      ['bought first from Store1','your customers',9],
      ['bought first from Store2','your customers',8],
      ['bought first from Store3','your customers',4],
      ['your customers','BOUGHT ONLY FROM YOU',27],
      ['your customers','bought later from Store2',9],
      ['your customers','bought later from Store4',7]]);
```

**What I would like in descending order of importance:**

1. All links which start or end at a note that has "you" in its title should be one color.
2. All notes which have "you" in its title should be one color.
3. The color of #1 should depend on #2.
4. All notes which refer to the same store should have the same color.

To achieve that I need to set the color of the notes and links independently.
Is that possible and if so how?

---

**EDIT 1: Solution**

I was hoping for a bit more direct control of the colors but I guess this is as good as it gets. The colors are actually used in a predictable way (see code) even if the notes get reordered so I can create the color array based on the data to display.

*Based on WhiteHat's answer:*

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Customers');
    data.addRows([
      ['BOUGHT FIRST FROM YOU',       // 01 new node -> 1st color
       'your customers',29],          // 02 new node -> 2nd color
      ['bought first from Store1',    // 03 new node -> 3rd color
       'your customers',9],           // 04 recuring node of 02 -> 2nd color
      ['bought first from Store2',    // 05 new node -> 4th color 
       'your customers',4],           // 06 recuring node of 02 -> 2nd color
      ['bought first from Store3',    // 07 new node -> 5th color
       'your customers',8],           // 08 recuring node of 02 -> 2nd color
      ['your customers',              // 09 recuring node of 02 -> 2nd color
       'BOUGHT ONLY FROM YOU',13],    // 10 new node -> 6th color
      ['your customers',              // 11 recuring node of 02 -> 2nd color
       'bought later from Store2',9], // 12 new node -> 7th color
      ['your customers',              // 13 recuring node of 02 -> 2nd color
       'bought later from Store4',7]  // 14 new node -> 8th color
    ]);

    var options = {
      sankey: {
        node: {
          // node colors will cycle thru array
          colors: [
            'magenta',
            'magenta',
            'cyan',
            'green',
            'yellow',
            'magenta',
            'green',
            'blue'
          ]
        },
        link: {
          colorMode: 'source'
        }

      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['sankey']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to color one node different from the rest,

use the `sankey.node.colors` config option

it takes an array of color strings which will be mapped to the nodes

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Customers');
    data.addRows([
      ['BOUGHT FIRST FROM YOU','your customers',29],
      ['bought first from Store1','your customers',9],
      ['bought first from Store2','your customers',8],
      ['bought first from Store3','your customers',4],
      ['your customers','BOUGHT ONLY FROM YOU',27],
      ['your customers','bought later from Store2',9],
      ['your customers','bought later from Store4',7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      sankey: {
        node: {
          // node colors will cycle thru array
          colors: [
            'magenta',
            'cyan',
            'cyan',
            'cyan'
          ]
        }
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['sankey']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, as for coloring links, it appears only one color can be provided...

Comment: thanks for you answer, however I am aware of that option and I'm using it already; also you can provide multiple colors for links in the same way ´link: { colors: arrayOfColors}´ (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/sankey#controlling-colors), however this does not help me, the graph just uses one color after the other as it sees fit, I have no control what color goes where and there is no guarantee for what place a link will have in the end so getting the order of colors right in the array would be pure luck

Comment: `link.colors` didn't seem to work for me -- but `node.colors` should map according to row and link -- only other option would be to modify the chart manually, once the `'ready'` event fires -- [here are a few examples](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39297924/5090771)

Comment: I considered modifying the chart manually but there is no easy way to identify the right rect for the note and the right path for the link, I could try to find the label based on its text, then look for a rect left or right of the label and so get the rect for the the start and end note of a link and then look for a link connecting to those two rects - or do you see an easier way of identifying the note-rects and links-paths?

Comment: the elements in the dom should follow the order of the rows in the data

Comment: ok cool - I'll try it out later - btw thanks for posting a fully working snippet - did not know that was possible - good to know for future posts